# Using Flux stores

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm working on a project which has only been going a very short time. There are few flux stores in place already which manage different aspects of the application state and are relatively independent.

I have 2 questions :

Some of the stores that exist are emitting more than one type of change event. Is this indicative of the stores handling too much unrelated data that should be in separate stores or is this a usual situation?

We need to write a React component that is dependent on more than one of the stores that already exist, and also needs to query the server to get some specific information to render on the page which it will then allow the user to modify. So, before this component can render, it needs to ensure all the stores contain what they need to and issue actions to populate anything that is missing. My question is about how to handle this. Would it be better to create a new store that fetches the specific data required by the component and is dependent on the other stores (using the usual flux store dependency rules), or to have the component knowing which specific stores it is dependent on directly.

Answer (score 0):

For first part of your question: it depends. Flux doesn't force you to follow strict set of rules. [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) for example, uses only one store for everything. I worked on project where almost all components had there own store and another one where we had single store per view that handled data model and all additional states. Without knowing specifics of your project (size, complexity etc.) I can't recommend one over the other. I would probably go with minimum number of stores that make sense to you and your team and refactor as needed (ie. when you feel it handles too much or single file contains too much of unrelated code). Whatever works best for your situation and makes you most comfortable.

For other part: since you want component to render only after data for all stores is populated I would introduce new store to handle server data and use Dispatcher’s `waitFor` method to define dependencies. If you opt to use stores directly you could then render component using some kind of intial state with loading spinner over parts that are missing or disable user editing and, once data is fetched, update state to display rest of the data/enable editing. This requires more code but can result with better UX. Again, it all depends on your needs.